# Can I import PostGIS raster data type into R by using the RPostgreSQL-package?

Tags: r, postgresql, postgis, rpostgresql

I have a PostgreSQL / PostGIS table with 30 rows (only 3 are shown) and 3 columns as follows
(`raster` is a PostGIS data type) - It's the EFSA CAPRI data set btw, if somebody's fimilar with it:

[image]

// Can I import the `raster` data type from PostGIS into R with the help of the RPostgreSQL-package (see the code below) OR do I have to use the rgdal-package inevitably as described by @Jot eN?

```
require(RPostgreSQL)
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "")
dbGetquery(con, "SELECT rid, rast, filename FROM schema.capri")
```

Importing it without transformation and `St_AsText(rast)` (which works for the geometry data type of PostGIS) don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an answer on gis.stackexchange page - https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/118401/20955:

```
library('raster')
library('rgdal')

dsn="PG:dbname='plots' host=localhost user='test' password='test' port=5432 schema='gisdata' table='map' mode=2"

ras <- readGDAL(dsn) # Get your file as SpatialGridDataFrame
ras2 <- raster(ras,1) # Convert the first Band to Raster
plot(ras2)
```

Additional info could be found here https://rpubs.com/dgolicher/6373

Comment: Thanks. It's not working with the RPostgreSQL-package? Your second link leads to a blank page.

Comment: Strange - the second link works for me. Maybe try again using different browser?

Comment: No second browser installed. I'm using Firefox 46.0.1 on Linux Mint. Without '/6373' I get to the website. Strange indeed - All articles there lead to blank pages for me..

Comment: My Add-block was the reason why I wasn't able to get to the website.

Answer (score 3):

If this is still relevant, at the University of Florida, David Bucklin and I have released a [rpostgis](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rpostgis) package that provides bi-directional transfer between PostGIS and R for vector and raster data. The package does not rely on GDAL (and rgdal), and should be platform independent.

Assuming that you already have a functional connection `con` established through `RPostgreSQL`, you can import PostGIS raster data type into R using the function `pgGetRast`, for instance:

```
library(rpostgis)
my_raster <- pgGetRast(con, c("schema", "raster_table"))
```

The function assumes that the raster tiles are stored in the column `"rast"` by default (as is the case for you), but you can change that with the argument `rast`. Now, depending on the size and other considerations, this may be significantly slower (but a lot more flexible) than using `rgdal`. We are still working on it, but this is the cost of providing a "pure R" solution. You can also use the `boundary` argument if you are only interested in a subset of the entire raster (which will significantly increase the loading time).

Note also that there is `pgGetGeom` for points/lines/polygons, instead of using `St_AsText`.